# How to save dynamically created textboxes and their values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on project in which I need to save dynamically created textboxes(I need the textboxes' data to appear when I run the application a second time).

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static int itimes = 0;
    static int i = 0;
    public void textboxadd()
    {            
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Name = "Name" + i;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            Point p = new Point(6, 43);
            txt.Location = p;
        }
        else
        {
            Point p = new Point(6, 43 + 32 * i); 
            txt.Location = p;
        }

        txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 26);

        Properties.Settings.Default.name1 = txt.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();


        groupBox1.Controls.Add(txt);

        i++;           
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        textboxadd();
        int gps = groupBox1.Size.Height;
        if (itimes == 0)
        {
            itimes++;
        }
        else
        {
            groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(248, gps + 32);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't understand my question please ask and I will answer.

Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: Dear OP could you please explain us what you want to achieve exactly, examples would be appreciated.

Comment: what i understood from ypour question is , you are creating some textboxes at runtime and you want to store/keep them for later usage, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes I want to save this textboxes. and when i will fill this textboxes i want to save this values by clicking button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a list of these dynamically created controls a when you close your application store their values you want to safe for later use in a file.

1) Create a class which stores values you want. For instance, name, position, size and text. Mark this class and its properties with xml serialization attributes.

2) When you create a textbox, store it in a list.

3) When you close your application, list through the collection of textboxes and create an object for each one of them where you store that values.

4) Use `XmlSerializer` to permanently store these values on a hard drive.

5) When you start the application, check if your file exists and when it does, deserialize values from it to objects and dynamically create textboxes and set them with values you have saved earlier.

I beliave you can manage to write code by yourself. Bear in mind these instructions and you will achieve what you want.

Comment: Well, ther is a whole bunch of books in stores and video courses on the internet. If you are a beginner nearly every book about C# will teach you something. Just type a c# book to google and pick a book by a cover.

Comment: Is there another way to store data without using xml?

Comment: Of course. You can use text files or a database. But I think that xml serialization is the best choice.

Comment: i am saying this because i don't know xml...    and can you tell me how by database?

Comment: create a table - control with columns 1.Id 2.Name 3.Location 4.Size. now from your c# code add each textbox property into respective table column before closing application. while loading the application read the values from database table - control and add the textboxes on your form.